Is it possible to start page numbering from the third page using the Google Docs API?
Currently, the page numbers in our document begin from the Table of Contents page (2). However, we want the page numbering to start from the "Third Page"(3) section instead. How can this be achieved using the Google Docs API?
I tried creating a mock template.docx where I added three blank pages at the beginning. On the third page, I inserted a footer and set the page number to start at 1. However, this approach did not work as expected. How can I correctly configure the page numbering to start from the third page using the Google Docs API?

As far as I know, the current stage of your issue is not supported at this time. You may opt to file a feature request using this link.
